# Is it possible to convert List of Outlook.AppointmentItem objects to a single ICS file in C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I have got a `List<Outlook.AppointmentItem>` which I would like to add all events in that list in to a single iCal (.ICS) file.

I have managed to create one ics file for each appointment item. But I need all of the items into a same ics file.

```
private void CreateOutlookAppts(List<Event> evts)
{
    appts = new List<Outlook.AppointmentItem>();
    Outlook.Application outlook = new Outlook.Application();
    int count = 1;
    foreach (Event evt in evts)
    {
        Outlook.AppointmentItem appt =
                            outlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
        appt.Duration = 60;
        appt.Start = evt.EventTime;
        appt.Subject = "xxxxxx";
        appt.SaveAs(@"c:\test\ical_appts\appt_" + count + ".ics", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olICal);
        appts.Add(appt);
        count++;
    }
```

}

Is it possible to possible to achieve this using any of the Microsoft Outlook reference menthods or by any other efficient means?

Thanks, Shivram.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Outlook object model doesn't proide any property or method for that. You may consider saving each appointment using the **SaveAs** method and then combining all appointments into a single ics file reading the file content on the disk, i.e. merging files content.